# English Language Learner chat room

Tags: discussion

could you please give me a link to reach English language Learner chat room so that I could chat there. I'm using mobile.Can I chat there?

I couldn't find the chat room for Learning English Language.

Comment: Oh wow. Someone's actually looking for chat! I can't believe my DEAD eyes.

Answer (score 7):

The chat link is at the very bottom of the page on mobile to the right of the meta link.

[image: Bottom navigation bar]

Here are the chat rooms listed for ELL. The second one in this list "ELL's Cabin" is the main chat room for ELL, as the description states. This is from the full-site view but it should be largely the same on mobile.

[image: Chat rooms listing]

Comment: No, I couldn't find. Please copy the link and give me a direct link plsease.Thanks

Comment: I could find the chat room, but couln't find Ell chat room

Comment: @yubrajsharma all of the rooms on that page **are** ELL chat rooms... The main chat room is called "ELL's Cabin"... which, if you read the room descriptions, you can see.